# How is the first derivated calculated in the following example?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I saw a differentiation as follows and I am a bit confused.
The function is: $h(t) = 96t - 16t^2$
The first derivative is of course $96 - 32t$ but the approach was:
\begin{align}
\frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{96(t + \frac{1}{2}dt) - 96(t - \frac{1}{2}dt)}{dt} - \frac{
16(t + \frac{1}{2}dt)^2 - 16(t - \frac{1}{2}dt)^2
}{dt} = 96 -32t
\end{align}

Where am I confused?
1) This gives $96dt - 32tdt$. So how do we ignore the $dt$ part? Shouldn't then it be $\frac{dh}{(dt)^2}$?
2) I assume that $t + \frac{1}{2}dt$,  $t - \frac{1}{2}dt$ symbolizes $t_2 - t_1$ but why not $t_2=t+dt, t_1=t-dt$? This gives completely wrong result if I plug it in the formula above but still I am not clear how that makes a difference as it seems valid substitution.

Comment: I guess you mean "$96t - 16t^2$" instead of "$96t - 16t_2$"?

Comment: @MPW:Yes I corrected it. Sorry I was trying to figure out the notation to use for the post and I did a typo. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to correct your confusion.

1) When you do the algebra on the big expression you typed, you do indeed get $96 - 32t$, not $96dt - 32tdt$. This is because the 'divided by dt' is already in that expression.

2) You are correct in that $t_1 = t - \frac{1}{2} dt$ and $t_2 = t + \frac{1}{2} dt$ is what is meant. The reason that there is that $\frac{1}{2}$ there is to make $t_2 - t_1 = dt$; that is, $dt$ needs to be the width of the interval. If $t_1 = t - dt$ and $t_2 = t + dt$, then the width of the interval $t_2 - t_1 = 2dt$, and then we really should be dividing by $2dt$ in your original expression.

Answer (score 1):

Definition. $\frac {dh(t)}{dt}=\lim_{\delta\to 0}\frac {h(t+\delta)-h(t)}{\delta}.$

The RHS of your displayed line , when re-arranged, is equal to $$V= \frac {h(t+\delta /2)-h(t-\delta /2)}{\delta}.$$ ....$V$ is just a conveniently chosen abbreviation.

$$\text {Let } \delta /2=\delta^*.\quad \text {Then }\quad  V=  \frac {1}{2}(F+G)$$ $$\text {where }\quad F=\frac {h(t+\delta^*) -h(t)}{\delta ^*},$$  $$\text {and }\quad G=\frac {h(t)-h(t-\delta^*)}{\delta^*}.$$ Since  $\delta^*=\delta /2\to 0$ when $\delta\to 0,$ we see from the definition of $\frac {dh(t)}{dt}$ that both $F$ and $G$ converge to $\frac {dh(t)}{dt}$ as $\delta\to 0,$ so their average $V=\frac {1}{2}(F+G)$ will also converge to $\frac {dh(t)}{dt}. $

$V$ is the slope of the line $L$ passing through the points $(t+\delta /2, h(t+\delta /2)),\;$ $(t-\delta /2,h(t-\delta /2)).$

It turns out  when $h(t)$ is a quadratic function of $t$, that $V$ is exactly equal to  $\frac {dh(t)}{dt}.$ That is,  $L$ is parallel to the  line that goes through the point $(t,h(t))$ and is tangent to the graph of $h$ at that point. This is NOT generally  true for non-quadratic functions.

This accounts for the apparently missing terms containing $dt$ on your RHS.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding it but does the F and G definitions have a typo? Why is it e.g.in G  $h(t-d^*2)$?

Comment: There was a typo. Thank you.

Comment: 1) Why are you using the notation $δ$ which does not show any association with t? 2) If F and G converge to the differential of $h(t)$ how is it proven that their average also converges to the same?

Comment: 1)...$\delta$ is not associated with $t $. For any particular (fixed) value of $t,$ the value of $h'(t)$ is as defined in the first line.... Note that $\lim_{x\to 0} Y=Z$ is just an abbreviation. Check the exact and complete def'n of  it. ...2)... This follows from the basic elementary properties of limits. I suggest you post this a  Q. You are likely to be quickly directed to an answer because  it, and related Q's on limits, have almost certainly been asked here before.

Comment: The denominator of $h'(t)$ is $δ$ because it is $t1 = t + δ, t0 =t , dt = (t1 - t0) = δ$. So it is the difference of `t`. So could you please explain a bit what you mean by `...δ is not associated with t`?